# Where can I find a good comparison of available custom ROMs?

Tags: custom-roms

I'm looking for a good comparison of custom ROMs' features and quality.  I would prefer a comparison that is actively maintained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Android Release Matrix](http://db.communityrelease.com/androidspin_release_matrix.asp) at AndroidSpin is pretty comprehensive.

There is also the [PDAdb.net Rom Respository](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=repository&list=rom_update), although I don't think it's as user friendsly as the AndroidSpin db.

Last (and least relevant to your question) is theunlockr's list of [Android Roms](http://theunlockr.com/downloads/android-downloads/android-roms/) (I just thought it was worth mentioning).