# Is there any custom firmware for the LG Optimus U?

Tags: custom-roms, lg-optimus-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

A quick search shows that I'm the only one on this site with an LG Optimus U, or the only person who's ever curious about them, but maybe I'm wrong.

I was wondering, does anyone know of any custom firmware / ROMs for the Optimus U? There are a ton for it's brothers, Optimus T, Optimus V, Vortex, Phoenix and Thrive, but none for poor little US Cellular, as far as I can find. :(

Comment: Is it actually different from the Optimus One?  As far as I can tell it's just the name and carrier.

Comment: I've read things about how the various brothers all differ and can't necessarily use eachothers tools. I just got my phone replaced so it has no apps or anything on it right now anyhow, so I might as well give it a shot. Thanks :)

Comment: Places to look for: [Where can I find a good comparison of available custom ROMs?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/16575), [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575)