# Definitive Guide to Customs Roms?

Tags: custom-roms

For those people who are interested in flashing custom roms after rooting their android device:

Does a website exist that provides a definitive, quick & up to date guide to the numerous and varied custom roms that are available for the android platform (obviously not the whole kaboosh, but something that gave a flavour). Generally I hear about CyanogenMod, MIUI & occasionally AOKP (if i'm not mistaken).

Fair enough if you have the time in the day to watch various youtube channels and do searches on the countless android orientated websites, i'm sure most people don't.

(I have seen similar questions asked here, generally people have named a few or just said see XDA)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find a good comparison of available custom ROMs?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/where-can-i-find-a-good-comparison-of-available-custom-roms)

Comment: Thx for that Izzy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such site that lists all the available ROM's for all the devices - if there was, it would be huge.

The best way to find a custom ROM, as well as ways to flash & guides, is to check the more popular forums - such as [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com) or the [Android Forums](http://androidforums.com).

Comment: Thats a shame, if someone came up with a site which listed 50% in a clear, logical and easy to access manner....I'm sure that would be good enough for most.

Comment: @Simon Even 50% would be loads. Think of *all* the Android devices out right now, each of them have more than 5 ROM's - some have as many as 20-50.

Comment: Anything between 1-5% would be helpful to most people looking at custom roms

Comment: @LiamW There are such sites. Just see what I linked as "possible duplicate" -- it mentions a bunch of sites, some of them are quite complete and up-to-date.

Comment: I have seen some of those sites previously, the Android Release Matrix doesnt look very friendly

Comment: What is the down vote for, downvoter?